# How do I dynamically get the value of a nested object property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following object:

```
let exampleObj = {
   hello: {
      there: {
         friend: 'my friend!',
         neighbor: 'neighbor!',
         world: 'world!'
      }
   }
}
```

Is there an efficient way I can create a function such as

```
function getPropValues(obj, ...keys) {
 // ...
}
```

where if I call `getPropValues` with the following arguments

```
const result = getPropValues(exampleObj, 'hello', 'there', 'world');
```

It would give me the result of `exampleObj['hello']['there']['world']`?

(i.e. I would expect `result` to be `'world!'` in this case)

Comment: `'hello', 'there', 'world'` reliably navigates to the property you want?

Comment: @connexo yes but I want the function to be able to dynamically do it, i.e. pass in any values. the object (and property names) will not always be the same. That was just an example.

Comment: I think connexo is asking if you need to support error cases (ie, is it possible the property doesn't exist)

Comment: you could mitigate that with hasOwnProperty though?

Comment: @NicholasTower oh okay -- no need to handle error cases, for this function, it is safe to assume we are passing in correct values and that they will exist in the object.

Comment: Does `lodash.get` fit your use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do this

```
function getPropValues(obj, ...keys) {
    return keys.reduce((p, c) => {
        return p[c]
    }, obj)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.` as a fallback to `undefined` for missing properties:

```js
const exampleObj = {
  hello: {
    there: {
      friend: 'my friend!',
      neighbor: 'neighbor!',
      world: 'world!'
    }
  }
};

const getVal = (ob, ...k) => k.reduce((o, k) => o?.[k], ob);

console.log( getVal(exampleObj, "hello", "there", "world") ); // "world!"
console.log( getVal(exampleObj, "hello", "stranger") );       // undefined
```

Or if you like a dotted string notation:
<sub>(Be careful since bug-prone. Properties can also have dots)</sub>

```js
const exampleObj = {
  hello: {
    there: {
      friend: 'my friend!',
      neighbor: 'neighbor!',
      world: 'world!'
    }
  }
};

const getVal = (ob, s) => s.split('.').reduce((o, k) => o?.[k], ob);

console.log( getVal(exampleObj, "hello.there.world") ); // "world!"
console.log( getVal(exampleObj, "hello.stranger") );    // undefined
```

Comment: This seems like a helpful comment on @dasi's answer

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using recursion.

```js
let exampleObj = {
  hello: {
    there: {
      friend: "my friend!",
      neighbor: "neighbor!",
      world: "world!",
    },
  },
};

function getPropValuesWithIndex(obj, keys, index) {
  if (index === keys.length - 1) return obj[keys[index]];
  return getPropValuesWithIndex(obj[keys[index]], keys, index + 1);
}

function getPropValues(obj, ...keys) {
  return getPropValuesWithIndex(obj, keys, 0);
}

const result1 = getPropValues(exampleObj, "hello", "there", "world");
console.log(result1);

const result2 = getPropValues(exampleObj, "hello", "there", "friend");
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much simpler recursive version in only one function, without using index.

```js
let exampleObj = {
  hello: {
    there: {
      friend: 'my friend!',
      neighbor: 'neighbor!',
      world: 'world!',
    },
  },
};

function getPropValues(obj, ...keys) {
  let currentObj;
  let key = keys.shift();
  if (keys.length && typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
    currentObj = obj[key];
    return getPropValues(currentObj, ...keys);
  } else return obj[key];
}

const result = getPropValues(exampleObj, 'hello', 'there', 'world');

console.log(result);
```